# application does not activate on clicking the application tile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i am developing a wp7 application.I deactivate the app by pressing the home button.After that when i press the app tile application is launched instead of activating.Is the default behavior of the OS or am i doing anything wrong.

if this is the default behavior then does the OS calls the previous instance's closing event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the default behaviour. There is a way to change it on wp8, but that doesn't work on wp7 AFAIK

Yup, double checked - this behaviour is called Fast Application Resume, but itsn't available on WP7

Comment: then what happens to the previous instance does it call its closing event

Comment: It will tombstone it, then remove it from memory, then re-launch it.